# SQL: How to get first row matching condition from either table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 tables,

**Issues**

```
|id|subject|assigned_to_id|
---------------------------
|1 |test   | 1            | 
|2 |test1  | NULL         | 
|3 |test3  | 2            |
```

**Journals**

```
|id|issue_id|notes|
-------------------
|1 |1       |NULL |
|2 |1       |test1|
|3 |2       |test |
```

**Journal Details**

```
|id|journal_id|prop_key      |old_value|value|
----------------------------------------------
|1 |1         |assigned_to_id|NULL     |1    |
```

`Journals` and `Journal details` tables are being used to maintain `Issue` history.

If some attribute of issue is updated, a `journal` entry is created along with `journal details` for each updated attribute. And if just a note is added to `issue`, only `journal` entry is created with that note.

Now I want to get the first journal record for the issue where either `note` is added or `assigned_to_id` is changed.

I am doing this via `join`

```
SELECT "journals".* FROM "journals" INNER JOIN "journal_details" ON "journal_details"."journal_id" = "journals"."id" WHERE "journals"."issue_id" = 1 AND ((journals.notes != '' AND journals.notes IS NOT NULL) OR (journal_details.prop_key = 'assigned_to_id' AND journal_details.value IS NOT NULL))  ORDER BY journals.id asc
```

but it only return the `journal` entry where `notes` is present.

```
|id|issue_id|notes|
-------------------
|2 |1       |test1|
```

I have tried `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but same result.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: I am using Postgresql

Comment: if you use outer join and right order, I'm sure it will return all rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM journals j 
left JOIN journal_det jd ON jd.journal_id = j.id 
WHERE j.issue_id = 1 
AND (
    (j.notes <> '' AND j.notes IS NOT NULL) 
    OR  ((jd.prop_key = 'assigned_to_id' AND jd.value IS NOT NULL))
    )
ORDER BY j.id ASC
```